# Sharing an audio file

Tags: android, button, audio, sharing

I am trying to share an audio file with a button, but when I click on it, the application shows a message "The file format isn't supported". How can I solve this? Here is my code

```
Button buonaseeera=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pulsantebuonaseeera);



    buonaseeera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audiobuonaseeera=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.buonaseeeraaudio);
            audiobuonaseeera.start();





    Button sharebutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
            sharebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String sharePath = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                            + "raw2sd";
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("audio/*");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Audio 
File"));
```

Comment: then maybe it´s an unsupported audio...which one is it?

Comment: Use the correct MIME type, rather than the wildcard.

Comment: It is an .mp3 audiio file

Answer (score 1):

Try this Example:

```
public class MusicPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Activity mactivity;
private Button btn_shareaudio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player);

        mactivity = this;

        btn_shareaudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_activity_music_player_shareaudio);

        btn_shareaudio.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {     
            File f = new File(/*Path of the song*/);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.getAbsolutePath());
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            share.setType("audio/*");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            mactivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Song Shared Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
            }
       });
}
```

Comment: I am using this code for Android 7 version but file attachment is empty every time. What is the solution for it?

Comment: It will works fine with Nougat also. Please check have you taken the runtime permission to access of read and wirte for the external storage?