# Sharing an Audio wav file

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share the audio file in android using but didn't found any working solution.

In My app the app records and save the audio file named as audio_1.wav each time in the app directory and then provide the option for sharing it. So always it share the file with same name(audio_1.wav).

Also checked that it is creating the file correctly.
I tried to share the audio file with below code;

```
File f = new File(sharePath);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath());
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

But while sharing and selecting any app it show ***unable to attach File***.

Also Used FileProvider Class for Nougat Devices but it didn't worked as well.
Checked multiple SO Link as well:

[Sharing an audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167747/sharing-an-audio-file)

[Picking up an audio file android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944987/picking-up-an-audio-file-android)

Comment: What exactly is the value of `sharePath`, and where did it come from? Also, please use the actual MIME type, not a wildcard.

Comment: @CommonsWare, sharePath = /storage/emulated/0/BrainVocabUp/audio/audio_1.wav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to the code that you have:

- Replace `Uri uri = Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath());` with `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);`, to get a valid `Uri`
- Use `audio/wav`, not `audio/*`, for the MIME type

Your code will crash on Android 7.0+ with a `FileUriExposedException`. Use `FileProvider` for that, where you use `<external-path>` in your metadata XML resource and add the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag to your `Intent`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) for more.

Comment: Will FileProvider class also work for devices lower than Android 7.0

Comment: @AbhilashMaurya: `FileProvider` itself works on any Android device running Android 4.0.3 or higher. However, some apps on older devices might not be expecting a `content:` `Uri` (though they should). You could consider using `FileProvider` only on Android 7.0+ and using `Uri.fromFile()` on older devices.